# XML over TCP using PHP with soap (or anything else?)

Tags: php, xml, soap, tcp

I know that soap can send XML over http, is there any way to use it to send XML over TCP? Or is there a better way to do it with PHP? Thank you very much for any insight!

Comment: but HTTP is usually sent over TCP already.  Or do you mean you want to eliminate the HTTP layer completely?

Comment: Yes, I mean to send it just over tcp and not using the http layer. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: What is the real problem here, beyond just the question you have?  Why do you think you need to do it at the TCP level, firewall, performance, fun?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using PHP you can connect to an arbitrary port as a client (or listen for connections on an arbitrary port as a server) and send/receive XML right over TCP, or whatever other data you want.  You don't have to use HTTP or port 80 at all.

Comment: This got me started. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can just send raw XML in POST requests.

Comment: I'd say any request, not only POST ;)

Comment: Well, formatting XML in a GET query string would look pretty bad.